# Multiple rows into one

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I'm working on a MS Access 2010 database and I'm struggling more than expected with this.

I have these tables:

```
    tblBook:
    IDBook (key)
    Title

    tblUser:
    IDUser (key)
    Username

    tblOrder:
    IDOrder (key)
    IDUser (linked to tblUser)
    Date

    tblOrderBook:
    IDOrderBook (key)
    IDOrder (linked to tblOrder)
    IDBook (linked to tblBook)
```

A user can pick up to 3 books per order. I made a query that displays them like this, by IDOrderBook:

```
IDOrderBook |IDOrder | Username | Date | Title

6           |3       | John     | Aug 1| Harry Potter
5           |3       | John     | Aug 1| Lord of the Rings
4           |2       | Susan    | Jul 5| The Shining
3           |2       | Susan    | Jul 5| Huck Finn
2           |2       | Susan    | Jul 5| Peter Pan
1           |1       | Rita     | Jul 4| Harry Potter
```

Now I want something to show them by IDOrder like this:

```
IDOrder | Username | Date | Title1       | Title2    | Title3

3       | John     | Aug 1| Harry Potter | LoTR      |
2       | Susan    | Jul 5| The Shining  | Huck Finn | Peter Pan 
1       | Rita     | Jul 4| Harry Potter |           |
```

So with multiple titles in a single row. How do I build this query?

Thank you!

Comment: You will need to use a crosstab query, though i am unaware of access syntax for it....pivot?   Google access pivot and you should find examples.

Comment: Thanks you, that seems to be the path to go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is quite a difficult task. First, we create the column name. We do that by counting each record with an ID higher than the current one. Then, we pivot that column name, creating t

I'm going to base all these queries based on that query you've shared. We'll call that qry1.

The query creating the column names, qry2:

```
SELECT IDOrderBook, IDOrder, Username, Date, Title, 
    "Title" & (
        SELECT Count(*) 
        FROM qry1 s 
        WHERE q.IDOrder = s.IDOrder AND q.IDOrderBook >= s.IDOrderBook
    ) As ColumnName
FROM qry1 q
```

Then, we use a pivot (crosstab) query to create your desired result:

```
TRANSFORM First(Title)
SELECT IDOrder, Username, Date
FROM qry2
GROUP BY IDOrder, Username, Date
Pivot ColumnName
```

I leave merging these queries using subqueries as an exercise to the reader, I've split them for clarity.

Comment: Thank you Erik, I've got a good start in getting the column name with your help, works great. I'm having trouble with the pivot query though, it's not recognizing q.IDOrder or q.IDOrderBook. I guess I'm failing on the exercise you assigned me on how to put the two steps together, but I'm still experimenting here.